# Chart.js turn off all y axis and toggle them on / off

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

**What I have:**

After canvas is rendered I would like to see nothing:
no curves on canvas area and no y axis - *it actually works*

**Initial view:**

[image]

**What I need:**
After click on label (Dataset1, etc.) I would like to see both curve and its corresponding y axis - however I see only curve.

**repo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-charts-toggle-axis-visibility-z7elmq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a first glance, your code looks fine to me and I expected it to work just fine. After some debugging however, I found out that `chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden` is `null` when the dataset is hidden and `false`, when it is visible. Therefore, the `beforeLayout` callback function should be changed as follows to make it work.

```
chartPlugins = [{
  beforeLayout: chart =>
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((ds, i) => {
      let hidden = chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden !== false;
      chart.config.options.scales.yAxes[i].display = !hidden;
    })
}];
```

Please take a look at your amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-charts-toggle-axis-visibility-d4mvrb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).